# Running from Visual Studio VS Publish

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, datetime, iis

When I run my application from Visual Studio 2015, it works perfectly, but when I publish, then I open my application in the same server I found some issues related to date.
In Fact I found the date format in different

Comment: It's a little unclear whether you're running the published application on the same machine as you're running the application with VS. I'm not talking about where you're running the browser, but rather where IIS is running.

Comment: Yes, IIS is running in the same machine.

Comment: Okay, how about you [edit] your question to show the code that demonstrates the issue you are seeing. Typically this happens because one server is set to use one region and another server is set to use a different region. Or because there is code that mucks about with `CurrentUICulture`.

Comment: VE_MAX_DATE.Text = Convert.ToDateTime("10/06/2021").AddDays(2).ToString().Substring(0, 10); shows "12/06/2021" when I run from Visual Studio, But shows "10/08/2021" When I run from publish.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the Culture to solve your problem:

- Open IIS
- Select your website
- Open .NET Globalization
- From Culture tab, select required Culture and UI Culture.
- Do iisreset